# How can I secure the cloud database for my mobile app?

Tags: android, mysql, database, amazon-web-services, security

I'm working on a mobile app that has both local database and AWS RDS. Data needs to be passed both ways so that user data can be backed up and updated data can be sent to the app.  I set up an API to avoid putting database credentials in the app itself. The API triggers code hosted in the cloud to interact with the RDS.

As I understand, Android APK files can be easily hacked. I would like a solution for how to prevent someone from reverse engineering the app's API calls and getting private user data from the RDS. As it is currently, if someone knows how to format an API call they could access data belonging to any user.

Comment: You need to provide some sort of authentication (and probably authorization too). You can either create a custom solution or use something from Google (if you are distributing your APK through the official store).

Comment: I was worried about someone using the API to get sensitive data. I've since realized that I can ensure that any queries in the cloud-based code that request sensitive data must use a username and password as a filter.

Comment: @DanOwen You can't pass the username and password with each request because you'll need to check username and password with database every API call that increases the database queries. You can use the jwt token signed by secret key which can be verifyable at runtime without db query.

Comment: Thank you Kiran, I will look into that. I’m still a student and I don’t know best practices for most things!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an API Authorization mechanism. Normally APIs are protected with **`Authorization Token`** which is obtained by a successful login. When the user successfully logs in, you should issue the authorization token, Store in device shared preferences that need to be passed with further API calls. I suggest using [JWT](https://jwt.io/), simple and available in all major programming languages. Encode the user's unique identifier in JWT token and design your API such a way that the user can only create, read, update, delete based on the identity encoded in JWT. By this, suppose if user token is compromised, that token can be only used to misuse the user-specific data and not all the data in your database.

#### Consider the given flow for your reference.

[image: JWT Auth Flow]